# Gruntjs error:cannot find module 'xpath

Tags: javascript, grunt-plugins

Good morning when I run the `gruntjs` command, I get the error: `can not find module 'xpath`

It installed it with npm however it keeps coming out and the `package.json` does not update it.

Any idea thanks

Comment: Please translate your question to english before asking.

Comment: Can you add more details like - package.json snippet, screenshot of command you are executing etc.

Comment: there is also Stackoverflow in spanish if that suits you better Fabio. Stackoverflow en español -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/